# Visual Studio can't recognize DNN's DnnFilePicker

Tags: visual-studio, upload, include, dotnetnuke, filepicker

I'm using DnnFilePicker in my Settings.ascx of my module. Though when I run the program the DnnFilePicker works, Visual Studio keeps complaing about it in the designer.vb. I keep getting the Type 'DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls.DnnFilePicker' is not defined.

For some reason such a file extension doesn't exist. Normally I wouldn't complain because it works, but I need to get access to the variables of the FilePicker I made. Any ideas why Visual Studios can't find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project make a reference to "Dotnetnuke.Web.dll".  That is where the library of DotNetNuke webcontrols reside.